# Adjust a width and height to an image (Model-Blade) Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to adjust an image with a specific width and height, but it's echoed with blade and I don't know how to.

This is the code:

In blade:

```
<li style="text-align:center"><strong>Fotos:</strong>
    @forelse($publication->photos()->get() as $key => $photo)
    <div>
        {{ $photo->image }}
    </div>
    @empty
    EL usuario no ha agregado fotos
    @endforelse
</li>
```

In the model the method photos():

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('BookPublicationPhoto', 'published_book_id');
}
```

This is the result (Photo out of page width)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgcCZ.jpg

Have any idea of how I could proceed?

**Solution**

I had other model which has the `image`method so I just added the width and height:

```
public function getImageAttribute()
{
    return HTML::image('img/publication/'.$this->published_book_id.'/'.$this->image_file_name, '-', ['class' => 'thumb', 'width' => 150, 'height' => 200]);
}
```

Comment: what {{ $photo->image }} contains? Image URL or Image tag? Can you describe further.

Comment: Hello, @PandhiBhaumik thanks for answering. The output of `{{ $photo->image }}` is: <img src="http://kinbu.localhost/img/publication/3/Selección_065.png" class="thumb" alt="-">

Comment: wrong practice, why would you store whole image tag in DB?

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik Any suggestions?

Comment: no, your practice is right, I thought you're saving img tag in DB but you've used custom model method so its proper.

Comment: Thanks for commenting and answering @PandhiBhaumik you had enlighted me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install LaravelCollective package, and use below code to set height, width.

```
{{ HTML::image('image_url','image alt title',['width'=>'100','height'=>'200']) }}
```

Comment: I solutionated it. If you see I'm calling a method `image` this is defined in other model like: public function getImageAttribute()
    {
        return HTML::image('img/publication/'.$this->published_book_id.'/'.$this->image_file_name, '-', ['class' => 'thumb']);
    }  **so I just added the width and height as:**  public function getImageAttribute()
    {
        return HTML::image('img/publication/'.$this->published_book_id.'/'.$this->image_file_name, '-', ['class' => 'thumb', 'width' => 150, 'height' => 200]);
    }

Comment: I need to have 15 points in reputation. I can't :(, but hope help the marked answer

Comment: Thanks, For your concern